# Laravel :Try Download Excel : Class 'XMLWriter' not found

Tags: excel, laravel, download, xmlwriter

I am trying download html table as excel file, first in blade template I did this :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/download')}}" id="download_form">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <table class="table font-weight-bold w-100" id="excel_table">
...........
             <button type="submit" id="download" class="btn btn-success">Download to excel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#download').click(function(){
                var table_content = '<table>';
                table_content += $('#excel_table').html();
                table_content+= '</table>';
                $('#file_contente').val(table_content);
                $('#download_form').html();
            })
        })
    </script>
```

the in controller I tried this :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\XMLWriter;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
public function download(Request $req)
   

     {
            $filename = $req->stage." ".$req->group . '.xlsx';
            $temporary_html_file = './tmp_html/' .time() . '.html';
            file_put_contents($temporary_html_file, $req->file_contente);
            $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Html');
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($temporary_html_file);
    
                $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
            
            $writer->save($filename);
            header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
            readfile($filename);
            unlink($temporary_html_file);
            unlink($filename);
        }
```

I get this error :

> Class 'XMLWriter' not found A class import is missing You have a
> missing class import. Try importing this class:
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\XMLWriter.

Note the download is works correctly in locahost server

Answer (score 1):

Just enable gd and xmlwriter in your php extension.

```
extension=gd2
```